# cross compile gcc 10.1.0 for avr fails on linux

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, avr

I try to compile current gcc version 10.1.0 for avr on linux but it fails.

```
'/home/krud/git_my_checkout/first/own_components/gcc_install/gcc/gcc-10.1.0/build/gcc'
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions
-fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing
-Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-error=format-diag
-Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long
-Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
-DGENERATOR_FILE -fno-PIE -I. -Ibuild -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/build
-I../../gcc/../include  -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include  \
    -o build/genmodes.o ../../gcc/genmodes.c
/opt/avr_10.1.0/avr/bin/as: unrecognized option '--64'
```

As I see it tries to use the linux gcc to compile and link with avr-as which is
wrong. What did I wrong/ what can I change?

What I did:

```
make binutils
make gcc
```

with the following Makefile

```
PREFIX=/opt
VERSION_BINUTILS=2.34
VERSION_GCC=10.1.0
GCC_DOWNLOAD_SUBDIR=gcc-10.1.0
MPC_VERSION=1.0.3
MPFR_VERSION=3.1.4
GMP_VERSION=6.1.0

binutils:
    mkdir binutils
    ( cd binutils; \
        wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.34.tar.xz; \
        tar xf binutils-2.34.tar.xz ; \
        cd binutils-2.34 ; \
        mkdir build ; \
        cd build ; \
        ../configure --target=avr --prefix=$(PREFIX)/avr_$(VERSION_GCC) ;\
        make -j8 ; \
        sudo make install ; \
        )

gcc:
    mkdir gcc
    ( cd gcc; \
        wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/$(GCC_DOWNLOAD_SUBDIR)/gcc-$(VERSION_GCC).tar.xz ; \
        tar xf gcc-$(VERSION_GCC).tar.xz ; \
        cd gcc-$(VERSION_GCC)/ ; \
        wget https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpc-$(MPC_VERSION).tar.gz ; \
        tar xf mpc-$(MPC_VERSION).tar.gz ; \
        mv mpc-$(MPC_VERSION) ./mpc ; \
        wget https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/mpfr-$(MPFR_VERSION).tar.bz2 ; \
        tar xf mpfr-$(MPFR_VERSION).tar.bz2 ; \
        mv mpfr-$(MPFR_VERSION) ./mpfr ; \
        wget https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-$(GMP_VERSION).tar.bz2 ; \
        tar xf gmp-$(GMP_VERSION).tar.bz2 ; \
        mv gmp-$(GMP_VERSION) ./gmp ; \
        mkdir build ; \
        cd build ; \
        ../configure --prefix=$(PREFIX)/avr_$(VERSION_GCC) --target=avr --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-lto --disable-nls --disable-libssp ; \
        make -j8 ; \
        sudo make install ; \
        )
```

Comment: Did you ask on [`gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`  mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-help/) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gcc-help I got the following working solution:

> Looks like a PATH environment variable problem.  Do you have "." (dot)
> on your path?  In the gcc build tree, we create a script/link called
> as for the cross compiler to use.  But if you have dot on your path,
> before /usr/bin, then this script/link will be used with the native
> gcc instead of the native as, and your build can fail like this.

After removing . (dot) from my $PATH everything works fine!

BTW: gcc10 reduces code size on avr by >40% compared against 9.3. Great!

Comment: I would take a close look at the generated "40% smaller" code and verify that every bit of required code is still implemented in that smaller code. A few years ago, I have run into a `avr-gcc` corner cases where the compiler made the code smaller by removing instructions essential to the working of the program which were unambigously called for by the C source code. They eventually fixed that specific issue, but "40% smaller" definitely makes me suspicious without verifying the generated code.

Comment: @ndim: Quite clear. And less code size did not mean faster code. If nothing is inlined 40% is easy to achieve. I did not inspect the generated assembly but it seems the code is still working. If not, I will report :-)

Answer (score 1):

You've inadvertently broken your normal `gcc` by installing AVR binutils without `--exec-prefix`, and putting it in your `PATH`. What you see here is `g++` running `as` to assemble for the local machine, which appears to be a 64-bit system. Unfortunately the `as` it found in `PATH` doesn't know of that target. On e.g. Debian GNU/Linux, you can install binutils with support for multiple architectures from the package `binutils-multiarch`, or particular platforms in e.g. `binutils-avr`.

Your `gcc` should work normally once you remove `/opt/avr_10.1.0/avr/bin` from `$PATH`.

Comment: I had --prefix in binutils and gcc configure. So I don't believe that I break my host gcc, or did I see that also wrong? For fedora I can't install binutils in current version as they currently not deliver newest avr tools. gcc version for avr on fedora is gcc 9.2.

Comment: What I should change in my makefile to get both installation steps running? is it --exec-prefix=avr?

Comment: And I took a look into my /opt/avr_10.1.0/bin and all what I found starts with avr-. You meant to say that I have to change --exec-prefix only for configure in gcc?

Comment: `--prefix` is where the programs are installed, `--exec-prefix` is a prefix to what they're called. This allows you to have `avr-as` available simultaneously with `as`. Your problem is that you've overridden `as` with a program that doesn't support the local machine as target.

Comment: NO, I didn't. If I type `as --version` I get "GNU assembler version 2.34-3.fc32, This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-redhat-linux'" Seems to be ok. And as written in my 3rd comment, all my created tools from binutils in the /opt/avr_10.1.0/avr/bin path starts with avr-xxx. That looks fine to me. I can't follow in which step I miss which configure option. binutils or gcc. And what should --exec-prefix set to. Is it --exec-prefix=avr ? Would be very nice if you can pick the line from my posted makefile and change it and post in your answer. I will check!

Comment: Well then, I'm a little confused as to why your error message contains an explicitly named program you claim does not exist. `--exec-prefix` is normally set to the target triple for a cross compilation configuration, so it may be that's actually right in your build script, but it wasn't in the error you posted.

Comment: Ah! I got what you say... In /opt/avr_10.1.0/avr/bin/as I find all without avr- and so I see as there but this is configured for avr. In /opt/avr_10.1.0/bin/ I find all binaries with avr-xxx. But I did not add /opt/avr_10.1.0/avr/bin/as to my PATH during installation. So how can I fix the installation script that it would not pick /opt/avr_10.1.0/avr/bin/as ?

Comment: The big question is what does alter PATH. gcc shouldn't; it has its own search paths you can check with `-print-search-paths` and `-print-prog-name=as`.

Comment: The simple problem was having . (dot) on the path. This will result in conflicts in the build script. See answer I got from gcc-help. Thanks for your support!